# Visual Studio malloc limits

Tags: c++

I run the below code using visual studio on windows. I got error of "Unhandled exception at 0x00BA5EF2 in mem_test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000." when the code trying to assign 1 to a[0]. My machine has 64GB RAM which is way more than memory of 2^29 unsigned int needs. I would like to know what is the problem and whether it is possible to solve it? Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned int *a;
    int b = 1 << 29;
    a = (unsigned int *)malloc(b * sizeof(unsigned int));

    cout << "here1" << endl;

    //it crashed after print out "here1"

    a[0]=1;
    a[1]=0;
    cout << "here2" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your program is 64-bit as well? It wouldn't mean much for a system to be 64 bits if the program isn't.

Comment: Are you running this in 64-bit or 32-bit? You are attempting to create a memory space that covers half the addressable space of the process in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Note that just having that much memory doesn't mean one process can access all of it. And even if it could, that doesn't mean a single allocation can be that large. I'm not sure how many of these issues apply to this case, but I know that there are some quirks about 32-bit applications.

Comment: You made the schoolboy error of not checking the return value from `malloc()`

Comment: @WeatherVane that error is not exclusive to *schools* or *boys*.  It may come across as an insult.

Comment: @DrewDormann it's an *idiom* not a *literal* statement.

Comment: Why did you tag a C++ question [tag:c]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your pointer value after you malloc:

```
a = (unsigned int *)malloc(b * sizeof(unsigned int));
if ( a == NULL )
{
   //malloc failed. don't attempt to dereference that pointer.
}
```

Also, you're program needs to be compiled in 64-bit mode, just having a 64-bit OS doesn't mean any program can address more than 4GB of RAM.

Lastly, malloc can fail when there isn't a contiguous block of memory the requested size available. So if you are requesting large chunks of memory malloc can fail even if there is enough memory available on the heap if your heap is fragmented.